How to replace a model layer using TensorFlow 2.16?
The following works with TensorFlow 2.15:
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

inputs = Input(shape=(4,))
x = Dense(5, activation='relu')(inputs)
predictions = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='nadam')

print(model.layers)
model._self_tracked_trackables[1] = BatchNormalization()
print(model.layers)

Output:
[<keras.src.engine.input_layer.InputLayer object at 0x7f9324ba10c0>, <keras.src.layers.core.dense.Dense object at 0x7f931c1144c0>, <keras.src.layers.core.dense.Dense object at 0x7f931c116c80>]
[<keras.src.engine.input_layer.InputLayer object at 0x7f9324ba10c0>, <keras.src.layers.normalization.batch_normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x7f9324ba3280>, <keras.src.layers.core.dense.Dense object at 0x7f931c116c80>]

How can this be achieved with TensorFlow 2.16?
The model no longer has _self_tracked_trackables:
AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute '_self_tracked_trackables'

And trying to swap out a layer like so:
model.layers[1] = BatchNormalization()

or so
model._layers[1] = BatchNormalization()

or so
model.operations[1] = BatchNormalization()

does not change the content of model.layers.
print(model.layers)

outputs the following not only before, but also after this assignment:
[<InputLayer name=input_layer, built=True>, <Dense name=dense, built=True>, <Dense name=dense_1, built=True>]

(Background: I'm trying to update my frugally-deep library to the new TF version, and it relies on swapping layers to convert nested sequential models to functional models.)

model._operations[1] = BatchNormalization()

works.
Please keep the following in mind: This code is accessing a private member of the class. It's an undocumented implementation detail, which might change again in future TensorFlow versions.

Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

I'd love to, but I don't have a proper explanation. I'm accessing a private member of the class here. It's an undocumented implementation detail, which might change again in future TensorFlow versions.
